# Can I block some core code of my site for Google Speed Insight to improve the speed score?

Tags: seo, google-search, page-speed

I blocked some core jQuery files for the UA google lighthouse, I wonder if it actually works, or it just let me get a high score, essentially, google still thinks my score is low.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I dont think blocking google lighthose will speed your page rendering for Googles bot  Blocking "Googlebot" might. This is not a best practice, and presumably points to you needing to fix your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Google measures core web vitals via CrUX reports - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/

The metrics are measured in real world when real visitors visit your web page.

These real world metrics aren't going to change by removing some jQuery libraries for lighthouse UA. Those core metrics are the ones that are going to increasingly play the part as ranking signals.

Ref - https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/11/timing-for-page-experience

I believe you want to ultimately improve SE rankings by increasing page speed score. If that is the case, removing jQuery for specific user agents is not going to help.